# In C# is there a way to see the code that gets generated via an ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reverse-engineering, web-deployment, system-calls

I'm looking at code in an XYZ.aspx.cs that pertains to a drop down list. It is:

```
dt = SessionData.Report_RespondentAnswer(DateTime.Parse(tbFromDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                         DateTime.Parse(tbToDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                         SurveyID,
                                         SupplierID,
      LK_SurveyStatuses.GetResponseGroup_ResponseCodes(ddlResponseRange.SelectedValue),
      LK_SurveyStatuses.GetResponseGroup_ClientResponseCodes(ddlResponseRange.SelectedValue));
```

And this corresponds to a drop-down that looks like this:

```
ddlResponseRange.SelectedValue
```

is this possile?

[image]

Comment: Use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), you can view the code easily !!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - I will do this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your browser, Right Click -> View Source

This will show you the generated markup.

**Edit** Most browsers also have developer modes which are better for this sort of thing. Chrome for example has a great set of Developer Tools.